# How do you draw a custom view(e.g. Circle) on a View?

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, draw, android-custom-view

For my Pong clone, I am trying to draw a custom View from class Ball onto my View in class GamePanel. 
However it's nowhere to be seen on the screen at runtime.

```
public class Ball extends View {

private float posX;
private float posY;
private float radius;

private Paint paint;

public Ball(Context context, float posX, float posY, float radius){
    super(context);
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.radius = radius;
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    init();

}

private void init(){

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawCircle(posX, posY, radius, paint);

}
```

Now this is my class GamePanel.

```
public class GamePanel extends View implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{

private Context context;

//Screen height and width in pixels
private static int width;
private static int height;

private MainThread thread;

private Rect paddle1;
private Rect paddle2;

private Ball ball;

private Paint paint;

//Starting position paddle1
private int xPos1;
private int yPos1;

// Starting position paddle2
private int xPos2;
private int yPos2;

//Width and height of paddles
private int pWidth;
private int pHeight;

private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;

public GamePanel(Context context) {

    super(context);

    this.context = context;

    //Information we will need for positioning our objects inside the panel
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();

    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    //Make the GamePanel focusable
    setFocusable(true);

    // Thread needs information about the game panel
    thread = new MainThread(this);

    pWidth = 100;
    pHeight = height/2;

    xPos1 = width/15;
    yPos1 = 0;

    xPos2 = width - xPos1 - pWidth;
    yPos1 = 0;

    paddle1 = new Rect(xPos1, yPos1, xPos1 + pWidth, yPos1 + pHeight);
    paddle2 = new Rect(xPos2, yPos2, xPos2 + pWidth, yPos2 + pHeight);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    ball = new Ball(context, 300, 300, 300);

    setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, this);

    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawRect(paddle1, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(paddle2, paint);

}
```

I tried calling invalidate() and postInvalidate() inside my MainThread thread, in the constructor of GamePanel and in the constructor of Ball. The ball is never drawn onto the screen.

As you can see I already faced this problem with the paddles in Pong therefore I created two Rectangles inside GamePanel which is very ugly.

How do I encapsulate the rectangle and the circle (ball) so that it can still be drawn on a Canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the **Ball(circle)** view inside **GamePanel** view. Just because you are creating a view that doesn't means it will be drawn on screen. You need to attach your view to the layout.
The simple solution will be to extend your **GamePanel** to **Ball**

```
public class GamePanel extends Ball {

}
```

then in **onDraw()** function of the `GamePanel` add `super.onDraw();`

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(); //Will draw the circle before drawing rectangle
    canvas.drawRect(paddle1, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(paddle2, paint);    
}
```

if you place the `super.onDraw()` below the `drawRect` then the circle will be drawn after drawing the rect.

> You also need to understand the basic concept of adding the view to
>   layout.

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering. I understand your approach. A question: What if I wanted to add multiple custom views and draw them in GamePanel? So I mean what if I also were to encapsulate the Rectangles into its own class like the Ball? Would I let GamePanel extend from ViewGroup or a layout type and add the custom views into there?

Comment: Let me list down the cases. If you are not going to move those shapes, then it is better to extend the GamePanel to ViewGroup and create shapes as separate view like you created "Ball" and add those views to GmePanel. But if you are going to move or translate shapes like rectangle and circle dynamically to any position inside GamePanel, then it is better to move their functionalities inside another class(Not separate view) and initialize inside your GamePanel. See this project library for example https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView

Comment: Ok I see. I have already put the Ball into a separate class as you know. I can't put them into a ViewGroup, because they need to be dynamic.Which class would it need to extend now and where do I initialize it in GamePanel/where do I tell it to draw the Ball in GamePanel? Sorry for asking so much basic stuff. I am new to Android developing and I've been hunting on how I can encapsulate the rectangle and ball for days. It seems so simple, but I can't figure it out somehow. Thank you for helping me

Comment: No issues :) You need to extend the GamePanel to View and other shape classes should not extend anything. initialize all the class (Ball) in your GamePanel's constructor. Then calculate where to draw all the shapes. If you are using touch as input, then pass the touch event to all the shapes class. They should calculate their drawing positions. In the sameway, when the onDraw of your GamePanel is called, pass the canvas object to all other shape class and let them draw using their own calculated locations.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's so obvious now that I see it.